How to get input values from a variable-length table
I have an Angular app that has a variable-length table in which I want the user to be able to enter input values for each row.
This is the bare-bones of what I'm trying to do.
After user has selected several files from a p-fileUpload, I want to be able to display each file in a table and allow them to add additional data (metadata) for each record.
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let file of files; let ii = index">
    <td>{{ file.name }}</td>    
    <td>{{ file.size }}</td>   
    <td>{{ file.type }}</td>                   
    <td>
      <!--Would like to be able to grab this value here-->
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

I think this should be relatively simple, but so far I haven't been able to come up with a solution.  If I try to do it by assigning a formControlName or an ngModel to the text input those don't really work because they're intended for a single input component rather than one of several in a table.
Is there any way to assign the input in each row its own unique identifier and then grab the value in the ts file?
Thanks!

The ngModel is a good choice to solve this problem. All you need to do is make sure, the name and id attributes have a unique name, which can be done by using the index of the table *ngFor loop. The final important thing is that you need to store the data in the current row data object (file).
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let file of files; let ii = index">
    <td>{{ file.name }}</td>    
    <td>{{ file.size }}</td>   
    <td>{{ file.type }}</td>                   
    <td>
      <!--Would like to be able to grab this value here-->
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Enter Title" 
        [name]="'custom-'+ii"
        [id]="'custom-'+ii"
        [(ngModel)]="file.customInput">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

